# SharePoint upgrade from Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 (Windows server 2008 R2) to SharePoint 2010 server (Windows server 2012 R2)

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

We are trying to upgrade SharePoint services 3.0 hosted on Windows server 2008 R2 to SharePoint 2010 Foundation on Windows server 2012 R2. We have followed the steps mentioned in http://www.sherweb.com/blog/sharepoint-2007-to-2010-migration-using-db-attach-method/ But when we try "Test-SPContentDatabase -Name WSS_Content -WebApplication http://wked0tdbs0002", we are getting loads of errors which we are not able to figure it out. Can someone advise on this?

```
Category        : MissingSiteDefinition
Error           : True
UpgradeBlocking : False
Message         : 4 Sites in database [WSS_Content] has reference(s) to a missing site definition, Id = [12001], Lcid = [1033]. 
Remedy          : The site definitions with Id 12001 is referenced in the database [WSS_Content], but is not installed on the current farm. The missi
                  ng site definition may cause upgrade to fail. Please install any solution which contains the site definition and restart upgrade if
                   necessary.

Category        : MissingFeature
Error           : True
UpgradeBlocking : False
Message         : Database [WSS_Content] has reference(s) to a missing feature: Id = [a4eb8c3b-aa25-4093-8330-39cdbb51b07c].
Remedy          : The feature with Id a4eb8c3b-aa25-4093-8330-39cdbb51b07c is referenced in the database [WSS_Content], but is not installed on the c
                  urrent farm. The missing feature may cause upgrade to fail. Please install any solution which contains the feature and restart upgr
                  ade if necessary.

Category        : MissingFeature
Error           : True
UpgradeBlocking : False
Message         : Database [WSS_Content] has reference(s) to a missing feature: Id = [4e72d346-276f-47b3-8d10-56e474a4fe4a].
Remedy          : The feature with Id 4e72d346-276f-47b3-8d10-56e474a4fe4a is referenced in the database [WSS_Content], but is not installed on the c
                  urrent farm. The missing feature may cause upgrade to fail. Please install any solution which contains the feature and restart upgr
                  ade if necessary.

Category        : MissingFeature
Error           : True
UpgradeBlocking : False
Message         : Database [WSS_Content] has reference(s) to a missing feature: Id = [49f204d6-28bc-4c76-af60-7960908119da].
Remedy          : The feature with Id 49f204d6-28bc-4c76-af60-7960908119da is referenced in the database [WSS_Content], but is not installed on the c
                  urrent farm. The missing feature may cause upgrade to fail. Please install any solution which contains the feature and restart upgr
                  ade if necessary.

Category        : MissingFeature
Error           : True
UpgradeBlocking : False
Message         : Database [WSS_Content] has reference(s) to a missing feature: Id = [310284e3-35d9-4b5d-99b5-c42147379877].
Remedy          : The feature with Id 310284e3-35d9-4b5d-99b5-c42147379877 is referenced in the database [WSS_Content], but is not installed on the c
                  urrent farm. The missing feature may cause upgrade to fail. Please install any solution which contains the feature and restart upgr
                  ade if necessary.

Category        : MissingSetupFile
Error           : True
UpgradeBlocking : False
Message         : File [Features\TfsDashboardBaseAgileContent\dashboardlayouts.aspx] is referenced [4] times in the database [WSS_Content], but is no
                  t installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this file.
Remedy          : One or more setup files are referenced in the database [WSS_Content], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any
                   feature or solution which contains these files.

Category        : MissingSetupFile
Error           : True
UpgradeBlocking : False
Message         : File [Features\TfsDashboardBaseUI\default.aspx] is referenced [4] times in the database [WSS_Content], but is not installed on the 
                  current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this file.
Remedy          : One or more setup files are referenced in the database [WSS_Content], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any
                   feature or solution which contains these files.

Category        : MissingSetupFile
Error           : True
UpgradeBlocking : False
Message         : File [themes\TFSDASHBOARDS\mossExtension.css] is referenced [4] times in the database [WSS_Content], but is not installed on the cu
                  rrent farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this file.
Remedy          : One or more setup files are referenced in the database [WSS_Content], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any
                   feature or solution which contains these files.

Category        : MissingSetupFile
Error           : True
UpgradeBlocking : False
Message         : File [themes\TFSDASHBOARDS\navBullet.gif] is referenced [4] times in the database [WSS_Content], but is not installed on the curren
                  t farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this file.
Remedy          : One or more setup files are referenced in the database [WSS_Content], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any
                   feature or solution which contains these files.

Category        : MissingSetupFile
Error           : True
UpgradeBlocking : False
Message         : File [themes\TFSDASHBOARDS\pagetitlebkgd.gif] is referenced [4] times in the database [WSS_Content], but is not installed on the cu
                  rrent farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this file.
Remedy          : One or more setup files are referenced in the database [WSS_Content], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any
                   feature or solution which contains these files.

Category        : MissingSetupFile
Error           : True
UpgradeBlocking : False
Message         : File [themes\TFSDASHBOARDS\siteactionsmenugrad.gif] is referenced [4] times in the database [WSS_Content], but is not installed on 
                  the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this file.
Remedy          : One or more setup files are referenced in the database [WSS_Content], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any
                   feature or solution which contains these files.

Category        : MissingSetupFile
Error           : True
UpgradeBlocking : False
Message         : File [themes\TFSDASHBOARDS\TFSDASHBOARDS.INF] is referenced [4] times in the database [WSS_Content], but is not installed on the cu
                  rrent farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this file.
Remedy          : One or more setup files are referenced in the database [WSS_Content], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any
                   feature or solution which contains these files.

Category        : MissingSetupFile
Error           : True
UpgradeBlocking : False
Message         : File [themes\TFSDASHBOARDS\theme.css] is referenced [4] times in the database [WSS_Content], but is not installed on the current fa
                  rm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this file.
Remedy          : One or more setup files are referenced in the database [WSS_Content], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any
                   feature or solution which contains these files.

Category        : MissingSetupFile
Error           : True
UpgradeBlocking : False
Message         : File [themes\TFSDASHBOARDS\topnavhover.gif] is referenced [4] times in the database [WSS_Content], but is not installed on the curr
                  ent farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this file.
Remedy          : One or more setup files are referenced in the database [WSS_Content], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any
                   feature or solution which contains these files.

Category        : MissingSetupFile
Error           : True
UpgradeBlocking : False
Message         : File [themes\TFSDASHBOARDS\topnavselected.gif] is referenced [4] times in the database [WSS_Content], but is not installed on the c
                  urrent farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this file.
Remedy          : One or more setup files are referenced in the database [WSS_Content], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any
                   feature or solution which contains these files.

Category        : MissingSetupFile
Error           : True
UpgradeBlocking : False
Message         : File [themes\TFSDASHBOARDS\topnavunselected.gif] is referenced [4] times in the database [WSS_Content], but is not installed on the
                   current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this file.
Remedy          : One or more setup files are referenced in the database [WSS_Content], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any
                   feature or solution which contains these files.

Category        : MissingWebPart
Error           : True
UpgradeBlocking : False
Message         : WebPart class [25b3392f-700b-7dfe-2cf0-601e115369af] is referenced [12] times in the database [WSS_Content], but is not installed o
                  n the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part.
Remedy          : One or more web parts are referenced in the database [WSS_Content], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any f
                  eature or solution which contains these web parts.

Category        : MissingWebPart
Error           : True
UpgradeBlocking : False
Message         : WebPart class [29b7265e-26df-6ccf-d0f5-edb9c68c35eb] is referenced [4] times in the database [WSS_Content], but is not installed on
                   the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part.
Remedy          : One or more web parts are referenced in the database [WSS_Content], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any f
                  eature or solution which contains these web parts.

Category        : MissingWebPart
Error           : True
UpgradeBlocking : False
Message         : WebPart class [108ba7b4-792a-e524-157d-f3a1e08be3d2] is referenced [4] times in the database [WSS_Content], but is not installed on
                   the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part.
Remedy          : One or more web parts are referenced in the database [WSS_Content], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any f
                  eature or solution which contains these web parts.

Category        : MissingWebPart
Error           : True
UpgradeBlocking : False
Message         : WebPart class [69f6fef4-17bf-5486-d8aa-fc6ea7fa146b] is referenced [4] times in the database [WSS_Content], but is not installed on
                   the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part.
Remedy          : One or more web parts are referenced in the database [WSS_Content], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any f
                  eature or solution which contains these web parts.
```

Answer (score 1):

**For `MissingSiteDefinition`**

Make sure that any solution that has the site definition has been deployed properly at `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\1033\XML`

If it's already deployed, just **restart** your server and run the `Test-SPContentDatabase` again, the warning should be now removed.

---

**For `MissingFeature`**

Try to install `SharePoint Feature Administration and Clean Up Tool` from [here](https://featureadmin.codeplex.com/) to clean up all the features, or deactivate the features from its related site. I mentioned all details at [Missing Server Side](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/03/05/missing-server-side-dependencies/)

---

**For `MissingSetup files`**

Try to delete it via PowerShell, I mentioned all details at [Missing Server Side](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/03/05/missing-server-side-dependencies/)

---

**For `MissingWebpart`**

Try to upgrade and deploy all the custom solutions to your new farm, if you don't have its solution, try to delete it as I mentioned  at [Missing Server Side](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/03/05/missing-server-side-dependencies/)